# How to create dynamic label within a datarow in a Microsoft Access Tabular Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, tabular

I have a Microsoft Access tabular Form which is bind to a single Microsoft Access Table.

In this tabular form I have several records shown as a tabular list. This works out of the box. What I need to do is following:

Add a Label to the datarow which displays a dynamically created text out of the values of the record field but the result should be dynamically and not static by writing the created value in a record field.

Example:

```
ROW1     ROW2     ROW3     DYN LABEL
------------------------------------
T1       T1.1     T2.1     L1+1.1+2.1
T2       T2.1     T2.2     L2+2.1+2.2
T3       T3.1     T2.3     L3+3.1+2.3
T4       T4.1     T2.4     L4+4.1+2.4
```

DYN LABL is a dynamically created label from the values of the table fields.

How can I do that in Microsoft Access (2010)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the form-designer open the recordsource-editor add the table you need, add the fields you need, then in the next empty field add something like this:

```
DynLabel: Row1 & '+' & Row2 & '+' & Row3
```

If you need to cut the Character at the beginning you can use mid(Row1;2) which means "only use this string from position 2.